# Determination of the species of a skull

Tags: species-identification

Out here in the mid german woods,  the kids found this skull:

[image]

Now we would like to figure out what it is. Started to look at various google image search results for all kinds of animals that came to our mind, but not only due to bad reception this takes long and lead to no result.

So what is a good structured way to start detrmining what this is?

Comment: What is the size of the skull? Could you measure it or make a photo with a euro coin next to it? Looking at it's teeth, it looks like a herbivore.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want people here to identify it or do you want to know how to identify an unidentified mammal skull?

Comment: @kmm: ideally I would like to have some information that can guide me to do such identification myself in the future; the skull here should serve as a kind of example people could explain some method, so in the end it should be identified here

Comment: @RHA: obviously you are right, that information is important. I will try that as soon as I have better network. For now the size is approximately 20cm I length

Comment: I usually use an old-fashioned book, but it's in Dutch. I imagine these kind of books exist in English (and German?), but I can't advise you on that.

Comment: @kmm If you seek a single question on 'how to identify a specimen from certain group of organism'; it would be too too broad. I think it is appropriate that anyone could upload specimens and experts could take part in identifying what specimen it could be. And obviously, why it is different from certain-other specimens, or in other very-close-specimens what similar things could be found, could be discussed in reasonable-amount of  words.

Comment: @PlasmaHH it looks to me like a skull of wild hog. Sorry I've too-little experience in zoology to identify an individual skull with characters.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: fair point being too broad. We could interpret it as identification plus thought process? I really would like to take away more than just the name from it

Comment: @PlasmaHH I din not told you question broad. The answer could be as short as only its technical name. I told Kmm that a single question to identify mammalian question is far from too broad. To do it, a big book will be less than enough.

Comment: And about results, it must be a young wild boar (Sus scrofa) or a domestic pig (please notice the very small canine).

Comment: Can you add photos of the occlusal surfaces of the teeth?

Comment: Tag add suggest Osteology

Comment: I changed the title of your question for it was in imperative mode. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you're serious about this (and it appears you are), you'll benefit by starting with a *Comparative Osteology* book or webiste that discusses all the various characteristics of skulls that give you clues to exactly what you're dealing with.

[This page on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123884373) has a variety of such books. Pages such as [this one](http://www.mainstreetsmiles.com/dental-and-skull-anatomy-of-carnivores-herbivores-and-omnivores/) begin with the basics and references help you to pursue the subject further.

On your specimen, although the missing teeth would be very helpful, important identifying features include the very large percentage of the cranium given over to the masseters, the eye socket placement, the size, the jaw shape, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Teeth are really important features for mammal identification.

The types of teeth gives an idea of the kind of food they eat.

In the skull you show, I guess that the tooth surface is far from being a "flat" grinder (which would be typical for an herbivorous, especially if old), but neither is there a sharp scissors-like structure (which would be typical of a carnivore). Therefore I will bet the animal is omnivorous.

The size, number, disposition and diversity of the teeth ([dental formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dentition#Dental_formulae_examples)) can further help. Some comments pointed to the presence of small nascent canines.

You can then look at a list of mammals that are living in the region of interest, filter it by size, and check what kind of dental formula they have.